# How to exit when the first error occurs for one of the goroutines within a wait Group?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine, worker

```
func getRecords(ctx context.Context, ids *[]Id) error {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, DefaultTimeout)
    defer cancel()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    size := len(*ids)
    allErrors := make(chan error, size)

    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(x int){
            err := //call to other func which return error type. nil or error
            if err != nil { // I will be creating n goroutines. How to exit rightaway if one of 
                            // them return error
                allErrors <- err 
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(allErrors)
    }
    return nil
}
```

How to exit on the anonymous function here?

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup ?

Comment: I have updated [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77755226/6309) with a [playground example](https://go.dev/play/p/ZBKkWnF-0na).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [ErrGroup](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup)

This is what ErrGroup.Go Does

> The first call to return a non-nil error cancels the group; its error
> will be returned by Wait.

So the other goroutines will be automatically canceled when any one of the goroutine return error.

Usage:

```
errs, ctx = errgroup.WithContext(ctx)

for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
    errs.Go( func() error{
        ...
    })
}

if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
    // Handle Errors from GoRoutines
}
```

**Edit:**
Maybe the answer was not descriptive enough. when the docs say other goroutines will be canceled, it means the `context` that was returned by `errGroup` will be issued a cancelation. So each go routine owner must handle this cancelation in their code.
*Example:* https://go.dev/play/p/hXWjtN4uj06

*Real World Example:* When your golang service starts, maybe you start a HTTP server in one routine, a Kafka consumer in another and say a grpc server in the last one. Now if any one of them stops, you want to stop the whole service (consider the service being down). Then you share the errGroupd context with all these goroutines (Luckily these underlying services already handle this context cancelation logic, so you don't have to write one) but if that goroutine does something custom then its the goroutine owner's responsibility to handle cancelation signal

Comment: g.Wait() returns until all the go routines return.

Comment: This is the wrong answer, as mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: @krig I don't think you understood the answer/golang docs. The routine stops only if you write logic for it to stop. As mentioned it cancels the group, meaning the context returned by the errgroup creation will be marked canceled. So each respective goroutine owner MUST handle cancelation signal.
Here is a sample code https://go.dev/play/p/hXWjtN4uj06

Comment: @JiankuanXing Added more description to explain what cancelation means. Its not like killing a goroutine, its more like a soft interrupt which you need to handle

Answer (score 2):

To exit when the first error occurs in one of the goroutines within a `sync.WaitGroup`, another approach (other than [`errgroup.Group`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup#Group)) would be to use a combination of a [context cancellation](https://go.dev/doc/database/cancel-operations) and [error handling](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/handle-errors). The main idea is to cancel all other goroutines as soon as one of them encounters an error.

Your `getRecords()` function would then be:

```golang
func getRecords(ctx context.Context, ids *[]Id) error {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, DefaultTimeout)
    defer cancel()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    size := len(*ids)
    allErrors := make(chan error, size)

    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(x int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            id, err := fetchRecord((*ids)[x]) // call to other func which return error type. nil or error
            if err != nil {
                select {
                case allErrors <- err:
                    cancel() // Cancel all goroutines
                    return
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    // Context already cancelled, do nothing
                    return
                }
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("Successfully fetched record with Id: %d\n", id)
            }
        }(i)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(allErrors)
    }()

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return ctx.Err() // Context was cancelled due to an error
    case err := <-allErrors:
        return err // Return the first error received
    }
}
```

That would make sure as soon as one goroutine reports an error, the context is cancelled, and all other goroutines are informed to stop their execution. The function then returns the first error that occurred.

You can see the `fetchRecord()` function in this [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ZBKkWnF-0na) which illustrate that idea.
Result:

```
Successfully fetched record with Id: 1
Successfully fetched record with Id: 4
Error: error fetching record with Id: 5
```

As soon as one record is not fetched (error), the other goroutines are canceled, and the first error is displayed.